# Hide/show DIVs in JS no longer working - potential conflict btw scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I used [this tutorial](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/) to hid/show DIVs. Unfortunately for some reason it's no longer working (I modified a few things in my code in the meantime)... Do you see where the issue come from? jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/C8B8g/
I think there's probably a conflict btw the 2 scripts below:

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('.textzone').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
            $(this).show(200);
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide(200);
        }
    });
}

$('.activity-title a').click(function(){
  $('.textzone').fadeOut(2000);
  var region = $(this).attr('data-region');    
  $('#' + region).fadeIn(2000);
})​
```

Comment: On the left hand side, you've chosen to have your javascript wrapped in an `onLoad` block. Change this to 'no-wrap body' - and then read about scope: http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems going on. You're missing `data-source` on your `<a>` elements. Their "region-source" is hidden inside of the href with some function. I removed that put it into `data-source` and now it all works fine.

You want to do something like this:

```
$('.activity-title a').click(function(){
    var region = $(this).attr('data-region'); 
    $('.textzone:visible').fadeOut(2000, function () { 
        $('#' + region).fadeIn(2000);
    });

    return false; // stops href from happening    
})​;

// HTML Structured like so:
<div class="source-title-box"><span class="activity-title">
    <a href="#" data-region="source-region">Our region</a></span>
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C8B8g/7/)

Comment: Hi mcpDesigns. Unfortunately this does not work in my case (it's a single page style website where each div is a page). Using your code because of the a href="#" it goes up to the top of the page when I click on the links

Comment: Just added `return false;` at the end (forgot it) that will stop the href="" from firing.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately still not working :-/ You can see a live version here http://goo.gl/ZzA1f page "the source". Could it be due to where my js is located? (in js/scripts.js)

Comment: You have the code outside of your Document.ready `$(document).ready(function () { '' put it here right after $("body").queryLoader2(); '' });`

Comment: Like this you mean? It doesn't work (have uploaded the updated code if you want to try) 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").queryLoader2();
   $('.activity-title a').click(function() {
        var region = $(this).attr('data-region');
        
        $('.textzone:visible').fadeOut(2000, function () {
            $('#' + region).fadeIn(2000);
        });

        return false;
        
    });​
});

Comment: You have a weird `**;â€‹**`​ symbol appearing at the end of the whole activity-title click function ->> `});`

Comment: Got it!!! There was an extra space after }); It's working like a charm now. Thanks A LOT!!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your markup in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8B8g/6/) that for every link (`.activity-title a`), there is a `.textzone`.  I removed the `onclick` event from these anchors.  This way The first link corresponds with the first `.textzone`:

```
<div id="source-container">
    <div id="source-region" class="textzone">
      <p><span class="activity-title">Interacting with the nature</span></p>
      <p>blablabla</p>
    </div>
    <div id="source-oursource" class="textzone">
        <p><span class="activity-title">Pure, pristine, and sustainable source</span></p>
        <p>blablabla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="source-title-box"><span class="activity-title"><a href="#">Our region</a></span></div>
    <div class="source-title-box"><span class="activity-title"><a href="#">Our source</a></span></div>
</div>​
```

Then with the script I simply use the `index` of the link which is clicked to determine the appropriate `.textzone` to show:

```
var textZones = $(".textzone");
var anchors = $('.activity-title a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = anchors.index(this);
    textZones.filter(":visible").fadeOut(2000, null, function() {
        textZones.eq(index).fadeIn(2000);        
    });
})​
```

Comment: Thanks John. I'll go for mcpDesigns solution, but thanks for your suggestion! Appreciate it